How to transfer data from google forms to sheets while maintaining the formulas already in place
I have a google form that automatically sends data to a google sheet when filled out. I need this data to be connected to certain formulas and right now have it set up to be connected to another sheet that formulates the resulted data. However when a result is filled out, it creates an entirely new row in the sheet and moves all my data around. How do I get it to not create an entirely new row in my sheet and instead just have it place the data in the sheet in the given row.
I have tried locking my formulas to stay on the cell that the data would enter into but it doesn't work.
I am not good with coding but I tried looking up multiple ways to code the data so it would do what I want but had no success.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us better understand your problem, please provide a publicly accessible sample sheet with sample data and the desired result.

1) not create an entirely new row in my sheet You can't-this is automated. 2) place the data in the sheet in the given row. Could be done with a script (triggered by onFormSubmit) but  is it necessary?  The question is silent on the layout and formulas on the formula sheet; maybe there is another solution. Truly, this sounds like an XY pproblem.
